# simpler(save memory) way to get all possible combinations in order of increasing length

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to get all the possible combinations of `listA` in order of increasing length. This is easy to do, but the current code I have returns `Memory error` once my list goes above 1000. How do I do the same with a code that does not use as much memory.

```html
original_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

#code:

modified_list= [original_list[i:j + 1] for i in range(len(original_list)) for j in range(i + 1, len(original_list))]

print(modified_list)

#output:

#nodified_list = [['1', '2'],['1', '2', '3'],['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                  ['2', '3'],['2', '3', '4'],['3', '4']]
```

I saw a similar code but this one prints all the combinations of all the elements inside the list.

```html
import itertools
List =  []
for L in range(0, len(original_list)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(original_list, L):
        subset = str(subset).replace('(','[').replace(')',']')                     #.replace(',','')
        List.append(subset)
```

Comment: You could use a generator expression: `subsets = (original_list[i:j + 1] for i in range(len(original_list)) for j in range(i + 1, len(original_list)))` and then consume samples one at a time (`for combination in subsets: ...`).

Comment: It's not the code that is taking up memory -- it's your data. Short answer, no there is no code you could write to shrink the memory required to store your data. If you don't need the whole thing all at once, then you could use a generator. Then, you're only storing a very small amount of data in memory at a time, but your data will also only be accessible one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

it's most probably that your modified list that takes up the memory...
try to print the `[original_list[i:j + 1]` without saving it in another list.
that shouldn't take more memory than your original list size.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Generator expression saves memory a lot, instead of `list` you can use this:

```
subsets = (original_list[i:j + 1] for i in range(len(original_list)) for j in range(i + 1, len(original_list)))
```

Also if you want to print, iterate through each element, do not convert to list.

```
for i in subsets:
    print(i)
```